# AS3 - How to drag an object in a line that is not vertical or horizontal

Tags: actionscript-3, drag

I would like to drag an object in one line.
I already know how to do this in a horizontal or vertical line

Here's how I do this

```
private var handle:Sprite;

private function init():void
{
    handle = new Sprite();
    handle.mouseChildren = false;
    handle.buttonMode = true;
    handle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    handle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 5);

    handle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startMove);
    handle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopMove); 
}

private function startMove(evt:MouseEvent):void
{               

    var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 1);
    handle.startDrag(false, bounds);

}

private function stopMove(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    handle.stopDrag();
}
```

But I want do drag my object in a line that isn't horizontal or vertical. 
For example, I would like to drag the object from the top left corner to the bottom right corner, in one straight line.

I tried to rotate the bounds rectangle, but it seems that you can not rotate a Rectangle.

How do I drag an object in a non-vertical (or non-horizontal) line?

Thank you very much!

Vincent

Comment: Have you tried using a rectangle with height greater than 1? e.g.`var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);`

Comment: @Adam, thanks for your reply. But when you set the height greqter than 1, you do not drag in one straight line anymore. I would like to have that my object just follows one line.

Comment: That was just guess, that's why I posted is as a comment. Another guess: have you tried rotating the parent container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use startdrag system to do it. You have to use an enterframe event and constraint x/y yourself :

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Test extends Sprite
    {
        private var handle:Sprite;

        public function Test()
        {
            handle = new Sprite();
            addChild(handle);
            handle.mouseChildren = false;
            handle.buttonMode = true;
            handle.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
            handle.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 5);

            handle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startMove);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopMove); 
        }

        private function startMove(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateClipPos);
        }

        private function stopMove(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateClipPos);
        }

        private function updateClipPos(e:Event) : void
        {
            if(mouseX < 100)
            {
                handle.x = mouseX;
                handle.y = handle.x;
            }
        }

    }
}
```